# Postgres GENERATED ALWAYS performance when adding new column

Tags: postgresql, performance, ddl, computed-column

I have a fairly big PostgreSQL 13 table that I need to add a new `TEXT` column and with this new column I would like to add a `GENERATED ALWAYS` column with the following definition:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD COLUMN text_col TEXT,
ADD COLUMN text_col__tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('pt_unaccent', "text_col")) STORED;
```

However when I run the above DDL it takes a long time to complete. As I understand that is because the `text_col__tsvector` need to run the expression for all rows in the table even if the `text_col` is `NULL`.

My question is: knowing that the `text_col` column will always start as `NULL` (no default value is defined) is there a way to make postgres skip the first generation part in the creation of the `text_col__tsvector`? Or change the expression part (`to_tsvector('pt_unaccent', "text_col")`) of the `GENERATED ALWAYS` column to ignore `NULL` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (postgresql 16) only stored generated columns are implemented and adding such a column [always](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_BETA3/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L7034) performs full table rewrite with the calculated and populated value. There is no way to avoid such table rewrite.

You can populate a field's value the old-fashioned way, using a trigger rather than a generated column. It is also possible that you do not need new column at all, but a [index on expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html). An index on expression can be built concurrently.